# Gulp-uglify not producing minified output file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, gulp, gulp-uglify

I've been trying to minify my js files, but I can't get gulp to produce an output file. To keep things simple, I created a test.js file in my root directory, and I'm trying to get gulp to compress and send a minified file to my public folder. I've been banging my head on this one for a while, so thanks in advance! Here's my app.js file

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var pump = require('pump');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'app_server', 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

gulp.task('compress', function(cb) {
  pump([
      gulp.src('./test.js'),
      uglify(),
      gulp.dest('./public')
    ],
    cb
  );
});
```

My test.js file

```
var myFunc = function(aa, bb) {
    return aa + bb;
};

myFunc(1, 2);
```

And my dependencies

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
    "pump": "^1.0.2"
  }
```

Comment: Do you get any output without the `uglify()` function? And what command are you using to execute this?

Comment: @Jerodev I tried it without uglify() and no such luck, also I'm not using a command, it's in my main app.js file so I expected it to run when my process starts

Comment: Can you  show how you include this file in your `app.js`?

Comment: @Jerodev when you mentioned running a command, I just had to run gulp compress and everything worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just had to install gulp globally, create a gulpFile.js in my root directory, and insert this content in the file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var pump = require('pump');

gulp.task('stream', function() {
    return watch('app_client/**/*.js', function() {
        pump([
            gulp.src([
                'app_client/app.js',
                'app_client/home/home.controller.js'
            ]),
              concat('loc8r.min.js'),
              uglify(),
              gulp.dest('./public/angular')
            ]
        );
    });
});
```

Then in the root directory, head over to the command line and run

```
gulp stream
```

This method deals with all error handling and automates the process so you don't have to use the CLI every time you update a js file

Comment: There is also a Vscode extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.minify that does the same thing (even using uglify) and also will work on css and html.